# CSCART: How to incorporate Product Samples on Product detail Pages

Tags: php, zend-framework, e-commerce, cs-cart

I am working on a site that sell Fabric Items, I have used CSCART as a Shopping Cart Solution for this. I ran into a problem, let me describe it briefly:

The website Owner wants to incorporate Product samples (which he calls it a Swatch [Definition: A sample, esp. of fabric.]). He needs a button on the Product Detail page which will work the same way as "Add to cart", instead of adding that Specific product into the cart it will add the swatch and the swatch price into the cart

In order to acaheive this:

1. I created a "swatch product".

But the problem arises is that, if someone ADD Swatch Product to his cart and checkout how come the administrator can know of which product the swatch is requested.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how CScart works, but this is a case where you have a couple of choices. You can either build a swatch product for each fabric `denim_swatch` and store it as a separate item or you can put a flag on each item you sell, so that if someone hits the swatch button it just sets a flag (a boolean) on the order for swatch or no swatch.

Comment: Good idea, I want to go with the second one, the first one will be difficult for the store administrator to manage,
But the problem with the second one is that, I can put boolean and store it in database, but The price that is added in card is the Product Actual Price and not the Swatch Price, so I want to incorporate the solution that will update the cost in the cart as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use product options feature of cscart. So you have to define swatch option along with price for that product. Now you just have to change layout of product detail page so whenever customer add swatch product to buy, product option will be used. In that case admin can see which products swatch option is ordered.

To know more about product options please visit this link - http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/user_guide/manage_products/options/product_options.html

Hope this will solve your purpose.